# How do I get the SSH key of my EB instance so that I can give it deployment access in BitBucket?

Tags: ssh, node.js, elastic-beanstalk, npm, bitbucket

I am building a node.js app that is hosted by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. One of the dependencies is hosted on BitBucket. I have specified the Git SSH url in the `package.json` file and everything works on my development machine.

BitBucket requires that the SSH key of be added to the "Deployment Keys" list before allowing npm to pull the code.

How do I get the SSH key of my EB instance so that I can add it to BitBucket?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate a keypair for your application to use. The private key gets deployed to your EB server, in whatever location your application needs, and the public key gets added to your list of deploy keys in Bitbucket.